# npx create-react-app struck then i have only node_modules , package.json, package-lock.json inside my folder and nothing else

Tags: reactjs, installation, npx

Whenever I try to run `npx create-react-app hello-world` I get this error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\Users\SUBHAJIT>cd E:\DIP_resrch\newton school\react dom example\demo2
C:\Users\SUBHAJIT>e:
E:\DIP_resrch\newton school\react dom example\demo2>npx create-react-app hello-w
orld
npx: installed 99 in 98.162s
Creating a new React app in E:\DIP_resrch\newton school\react dom example\demo2\
hello-world.
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall E:\   DIP_resrch\newton school\react dom example\demo2
\hello-world\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
> core-js@3.6.4 postinstall E:\DIP_resrch\newton school\react dom example\demo2\
hello-world\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
> core-js-pure@3.6.4 postinstall E:\DIP_resrch\newton school\react dom example\d
emo2\hello-world\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
+ cra-template@1.0.3
+ react-scripts@3.4.1
+ react@16.13.1
+ react-dom@16.13.1
added 1606 packages from 750 contributors and audited 931160 packages in 1344.41
s
58 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

After running it, I only have `node_modules`, `package.json`, and `package-lock.json` inside the folder. There's nothing else there. How can I fix this error so I can create the application?

Comment: npx says that everything has been installed correctly. Are you sure you are looking in the correct folder?

Comment: yes.. but I have no src and public folder inside that

Comment: Looks like you are using a very old version of Windows. I just tried creating an app on my Windows 10 and the beginning of the output looks basically identical. Though in my case after the "found 0 vulnerabilities" line npm writes "Initialized a git repository." and continues doing more things. Did you wait until npm finished its work? Also this first part of the install took me 120.145s while in your case it was 1344.41s, which suggests you have to be a lot more patient and npm isn't stuck :)